# Connecting to external database in iOS

Tags: ios, database, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I know I can use SQLlite and of course a clientdataset, but....
How do I connect to an **external** database over the internet in iOS using Firemonkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a blog page on EDN here, it uses a non-visual datasnap library:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41729
Link to the source code: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28579

The example connects to a remote Interbase, server, but it should be fairly easy to rewrite it to use other databases like MySQL.